# VB.net Perform task at scheduled Time

Tags: vb.net

i need to perform a task at a certain time using the using the user inputted Hour and Minute.

I'm thinking of something like using some sort of loop that every time it loops, checks if the  `Now().Hour` matches `HourChoice` and the `Now().Minute` matches the `MinuteChoice`

In this, i also have a user option to chose "AM" or "PM", and if `TimeOfDay = "PM"`, add 12 hours (The `Now().Hour` is military time).

EDIT:I only want this to run once at a time, not every day.

Comment: Is this a web app, desktop app, service?

Comment: @randcd a vb.net desktop application

Comment: for reference :  [Create scheduled task using VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20677722/327083)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `System.Threading.Timer` to do this.  Instead of a loop that constantly runs and sleeps, you could set the interval to the `Timer` to be the difference between now and the selected time and the `TimerCallback` to be the `Sub` that does the task work.  Setting the timeout to 0 or `Timeout.Infinite` will make sure this is only executed once.

EDIT: Example

```
Dim tcb As TimerCallback = AddressOf DoStuff
Dim t As Timer
Dim execTime As TimeSpan
Dim dtNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim hc As Integer = HourChoice
Dim mc As Integer = MinuteChoice

If TimeOfDay = "AM" And hc = 12 Then
    hc = 0
Else If TimeOfDay = "PM" Then
    hc = hc + 12
End If

Dim dtCandidate As DateTime = New DateTime(dtNow.Year, dtNow.Month, dtNow.Day, hc, mc, 0)

If dtCandidate < dtNow Then
    dtCandidate.AddDays(1)
End If

execTime = dtCandidate.Subtract(dtNow)
t = New Timer(tcb,Nothing,execTime,TimeSpan.Zero)
```

Then you just need a Sub to do your task:

```
Public Sub DoStuff(obj As Object)
'...Do Some Kind of Work
End Sub
```

Comment: Will you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to loop,
Simply add a Timer to your form, set its interval to 500 so that it fires every 500 milliseconds.
Enable it via a Button to start your Task.

Then on your Timer.Tick Event:

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
       If Hour(Now) = HourChoice And Minute(Now) = MinuteChoice Then
            'Your Task Here
       End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I would create a Timer, and set its tick to the given time to wait in milliseconds. When the timer is called you stop the timer.

Comment: That's a better approach @DavidSdot

Comment: how do i enable it and set the timer?

Comment: @DavidSdot how do i do that? I have never used a timer

Comment: A Timer is one of the object located on your Toolbox (Like a Button). You drag it to your form to add it, again like a Button.

Comment: to calc the milliseconds use sth. like
   `(Date.Now - Date.Now.AddHours(2)).TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: After fiddling around google, it seems that the Timer's Interval Property is maxed out at 64.8 seconds. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't that be 500 milliseconds and not 5 ms??

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but that should work. In the TimeSpan you can set days, hours, minutes, seconds.

```
Private timer As System.Threading.Timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf DoWhatever, Nothing, New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0), -1)

Private Sub dowhatever(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
   ' Do stuff
End Sub
```

More can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to add an answer to this question, but: You can use a standard System.Windows.Forms.Timer. Set the interval to the difference in milliseconds beween the required time and Now(), then start the timer.