# Create scheduled task using VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, task, schedule, windows-task-scheduler

How do I create a scheduled task using VB.NET - Populating Scheduled Task fields from vb.net program on button click?

I have nothing at the moment, nor do I even know if it is possible.

Answer (score 5):

You have to create wrappers around the native COM interfaces. If you don't want to do it yourself, you can use this library https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Get the service on the local machine
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
         td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

         // Remove the task we just created
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it at all possible to build code to schedule a task which will add the current user logged in to the computer to a local administrators group for 1 hour once the button is clicked in VB? Then removed after the hour.

Comment: Everything's possible, but you'll need to understand some Windows security mecanisms

Comment: codeplex link is now dead